# Why is my output only one row when i try outputting my dataframe to a csv file?Python3/boto3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv, boto3

I am trying to write the value of my bucket.name, and obj.key to a csv file with its respective value in its respective column.

When I run the code below, it only outputs one row to my csv file:

```
bucket_name | key_s3_path

value        , value
```

However the output of my ff variable is:

```
{'bucket_name': ["'mybucket', "], 'key_s3_path'["'my/file/path/80ece.txt', "]}
{'bucket_name': ["'mybucket', "], 'key_s3_path': ["'my/file/path/80ece.txt', "]}
{'bucket_name': ["'mybucket', "], 'key_s3_path': ["'my/file/path/80ece.txt', "]}
```

As you can see, there is three values, but it only writers one of the three values to the csv file.

Here is my code:

```
def load_into_csv(years):
    for year in years:
        for buckett in s3.buckets.all():
            for aobj in buckett.objects.filter(Bucket=bucket,Prefix=PREFIX):
                if year in aobj.key:
                   f= "'{}', ".format(buckett.name)
                   ff= "'{}', ".format(aobj.key)
                   #print(f)
                   dd = {'bucket_name':[f], 'key_s3_path':[ff]}
                    #print(dd)
                   df = pd.DataFrame(data=dd)
                    #print(df)
                   export_csv = df.to_csv (r'my/path/0177_s3_files_v2.csv', index = None, header=True)

years=['2017']
load_into_csv(years)
```

ANY IDEAS as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing your `export_csv()` inside the foor loop. So in every iteration you are overwriting the old `df` and also overwriting your `0177_s3_files_v2.csv`.

You should try to instead of overwriting df, append the values to df and then when your for loop ends write the csv.

Try something like this:

```
def load_into_csv(years):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for year in years:
        for buckett in s3.buckets.all():
            for aobj in buckett.objects.filter(Bucket=bucket,Prefix=PREFIX):
                if year in aobj.key:
                   f= "'{}', ".format(buckett.name)
                   ff= "'{}', ".format(aobj.key)
                   #print(f)
                   dd = {'bucket_name':[f], 'key_s3_path':[ff]}
                    #print(dd)
                   df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dd)
                   df = df.append(df_2, ignore_index=True)
    export_csv = df.to_csv (r'my/path/0177_s3_files_v2.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

> Edit: More efficient solution.

```
 def load_into_csv(years):
    list_dd = []
    for year in years:
        for buckett in s3.buckets.all():
            for aobj in buckett.objects.filter(Bucket=bucket,Prefix=PREFIX):
                if year in aobj.key:
                    f= "'{}', ".format(buckett.name)
                    ff= "'{}', ".format(aobj.key)
                    # Store into a list the bucket_name and the path.
                    list_dd.append( [f, ff] )

    # Create the dataframe with the list previusly generated.
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_dd, columns = ['bucket_name', 'key_s3_path'])
    export_csv = df.to_csv (r'my/path/0177_s3_files_v2.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

Comment: THANKS YOU!! YOU DESERVE A REWARD

Comment: Thank you!! It's always a pleasure to help ^^

Comment: This does work but it is offly slow. do you know a way to increase the speed? Writerrows perhaps?

Comment: This does work but it is offly slow. do you know a way to increase the speed? Writerrows perhaps?

Comment: Yes `append`is not a very efficient method. You can use a list to store your `dd` variable and when the loop ends create a final dataframe. See my edit